# Save command and using a variable as the path octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to get the **Save/Load command** to use a variable as the path in octave/matlab
I can save variables using the **Save/Load command**

```
save('/tmp/a1_var.mat','V1','V2')
```

But the path I use will change based on the location of the file.  How can I have the save/load command accept variables for the path/and or filename?

Example:

```
dirpath='/tmp/';
save(dirpath,'a1_var.mat','V1','V2')
```

I tried

```
save(strcat(dirpath),'a1_var.mat','V1','V2')
```

but I get an error ***save: unable to open output file***

Comment: Tried `save(strcat(dirpath,'a1_var.mat'),'V1','V2')`? I think `fullfile` might be safer instead of `strcat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to save is comma separated so your command

```
save(dirpath,'a1_var.mat','V1','V2')
```

is trying to save a variable called 'a1_var.mat' as this is after the first comma. The error message is because you have defined the filename as just the folder '/tmp/' rather than a file.

You need to group your pathname and filename into one string using square brackets []

```
save([dirpath,'a1_var.mat'],'V1','V2')
```